# Flexbox alignment in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox

In the attached Codepen, you will see that I am using Flexbox to align the Logo and Menu icons in the header. The logo should be aligned left, the menu icon right. (I have other elements but this is just a simplified version for demonstration).

When testing in IE11, I see that the Flexbox isn't working. As far as I can tell via the documentation, IE11 should be supporting this. I have other Flexbox elements, which are also not working.

As you can see, the prefix is added for IE10.

Is anyone able to tell me where I am going wrong here?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EWqvNv

Here is the CSS:

```
.container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-pack: end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}           

.nav-logo {
    margin-right: auto; 
}
```

Comment: here http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox,
it is mentioned that flexbox can be used partially in IE11.
I can not see the problem in chrome or firefox. You can also use 
    justify-content: space-between;
instead of flex-end;

Comment: The issue is only apparent in IE11. 
I have other elements in the header which also need to be aligned right. The 'space-between' option equally spaces the items I think.

Comment: then it is only the problem of ie11, sorry I didn't notice that you mentioned about other elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As IE11 is quite buggy, so if to remove the `justify-content: flex-end;`, it will work as intended

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NpQwwE)

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-logo {
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

  <header>

    <div class="container">

      <a class="nav-logo" href=""></a>

      <a class="nav-toggle" href="#">Menu</a>

    </div>

  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

---

Side note:

Based on the above left-to-right flow (omitted `justify-content` defaults to `flex-start`), I would use `margin-left: auto` on the `nav-toggle` instead, [sample codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NpQwLJ)

Answer (score 2):

Setting `justify-content: space-between` seems to work; why not use that?

Answer (score -1):

I'm Sorry but if you look at https://caniuse.com/#search=justify-content it's clear that IE doesn't support this method. To fixed that problem on IE you can use extra css like so:

```css
.container {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
  position: relative;
    @supports(justify-content: space-between) {
      -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
      -ms-flex-pack: end;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
}      

.nav-logo {
 margin-right: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
}

.nav-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  @supports(justify-content: space-between) {
    position: unset;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
 
 <head></head>
 
 <body>
  
  <header>
 
   <div class="container">
     
    <a class="nav-logo" href=""></a>
 
    <a class="nav-toggle" href="#">Menu</a>
    
   </div>
     
  </header>
   
 </body>
 
</html>
```

Comment: `space-evenly` doesn't work in IE, but here is asked about `space-between`, which works just fine in IE, so your answer is unfortunately wrong.

Comment: It's not clear. I came here because icanuse doesn't give a clear answer on whether space-between is supported on IE11. It's not even mentioned.